# JavaPairRDD convert key-value into key-list

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a JavaPairRDD containing (Key, Value) which I want to group by Keys and make the "second column" a list with all values seen for that key. I am currently using the `groupby()` function, which does the key aggrupation correctly but converts my values to an Iterable of Long. This is,

```
Key1 Iterable<Long>
Key2 Iterable<Long>
...
```

Is there any way to force this function to use a List of Longs instead of an Iterable object?

```
Key1 List<Long>
Key2 List<Long>
...
```

I read something about a function called `combineByKey()` but I think this is not a use case. Probably I need to use reduceByKey but I am not seeing it. It should be something like this:

```
myRDD.reduceByKey((a,b) -> new ArrayList<Long>()) //and add b to a
```

In the end, I want to combine values to obtain a Key n, `List<Long>` RDD.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```java
JavaPairRDD <String, List<long>> keyValuePairs = rdd.map(t -> {
    return new Tuple2(t._1, Arrays.asList(new long[]{t._2}));
}).reduceByKey((a, b) -> {
    a.addAll(b);
    return a;
});
```

First, you map to convert the value into a list of longs. Then reduceByKey and combine the lists using `addAll` method on arraylist.